# file_get_contents() failing to read file if it contains "<body>" inside

Tags: php, json, file, file-get-contents

I am uploading a .json file to server and using file_get_contents(), reading the content out of it. The file contains "`<body>`" as a value of a json key. The file_get_contents() function is returning a

```
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
```

instead of the string.

- I have tried `mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES',
  "UTF-8");`
- I have tried `htmlentities()`
- I have tried to simple `fopen` read mode and output
- I have tried`mb_convert_encoding($content,
  'UTF-8',mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));`

I tried simple text "abc`<body>`dfg" in a text file and do file_get_contents().
All are failing and giving same output. Any help will be appreciated.
I cannot use cURL as the file resides out of my root dir.

```
try{
    if (0<$_FILES['file']['error']){
             echo 'Err: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
     }else{
          $filename = time() . $_FILES['file']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '/tmp/'.$filename);
     }
     echo file_get_contents('/tmp/'.$filename);
}catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

[image]

The file contains string "blah blah `<body>` blah blah"
Output : blah blah `<script>`Some JS Code`</script><body>` blah blah

Comment: Are you outputting this to a browser...?

Comment: No I am just putting an echo to check. `echo file_get_contents('/tmp/'.$filename);`

Comment: I miss some code you use. Without it, this will be dancing in the dark. So please post some code.

Comment: Plz check the edit

Comment: What is your output if you do not print the file content?

Answer (score 1):

This JavaScript code belongs to [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/) monitoring system. It code gets appended automatically by a PHP/Apache module as long as it's active on your server. Check out the server configuration and disable it, if you manage server by yourself, otherwise contact hosting support team.

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting RAW file content to a browser. Use `var_dump(file_get_contents('/tmp/'.$filename))` instead.

Comment: Tried that too!! Not working. But isn't the function able to handle <body> as a simple substring?

Comment: You say that `The file_get_contents() function is returning a <script type="text/javascript">...</script>`. Meanwhile I am sure that it can not change the read data in any way. Could you show a screenshot from your browser after `var_dump(file_get_contents('/tmp/'.$filename))`?

Comment: Attached screenshot